# Is there an Azure scripting API that does not persist credentials in clear text?

Tags: azure, scripting, credentials

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2019, on-prem.

I am currently using Azure CLI Task in my build pipeline. The problem - it persists the service principal credentials in clear text for the duration of the task.

Is there a scripting API that does not do it? E.g. it could require credentials for every command. At the very least it could encrypt the credentials using DPAPI. Not ideal, but better than clear text.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/.

Comment: Please, elaborate how it is helpful.